# Self-hosting Mercurial repositories with Trac

Tags: macos, server, mercurial, host, trac

Since the change with Bitbucket (remove mercurial support), I wanted to host myself the repositories I use.

I searched the options available here https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialHosting
and decided to test Trac, because I didn't want to use and administer an Apache server (just for simplicity).

All went good, I was able to install and run the software, I see my test-repository with my navigator on my server, in the Browse source of Trac's tab, but...
I cannot find how I can access the repository as a server repository, which URL should I use to Push/Pull to my local repository.

I think I missed something, is Trac able to host my repositories, or is it just a ticket system?

Comment: Have you read about `hg serve` ?

Comment: @DaveInCaz: Yep, but hg serve just let me clone the repositories, not push or pull, if I understand... I think I'll have to try Kallithea, with Apache and a database

Comment: No, you can do everything with hg serve. Push, pull, all operations work normally. I use it that way daily.

Comment: I didn't found much informations for hg serve, even serving more than one repository is not good documented, but in the definitive guide http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html#sec:collab:serve It's noted `In particular, hg serve won't allow remote users to modify your repository. It's intended for read-only use`  I don't know how to use all the options, and MacHG (GUI client) just propose to clone from server

Comment: Their statement is false. We use it for push all the time. Maybe that document is very old / out of date? (in fact, it is from 2009 or older)

Comment: Anyway, hg serve is very easy just to try out and see if it works for you. It requires no setup, configuration, or dedicated hardware.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find how I can access the repository as a server repository, which URL should I use to Push/Pull to my local repository

Because Trac isn't web-server for HG, it's just frontend to local (for Trac) repository.

If you want to have repo http-accessible, you still have to do it (but while you have *something* for Trac, it can be used for Mercurial too). For local usage you still use file-path to repo-folder "as is"